# How To Distribute Value Evenly Across An Array Using Whole Values

Tags: arrays, integer, distribution, percentage

Given any integer value, I want to be able to evenly distribute the value across an array of non-negative integers such that each array cell is increased an amount relative to its current value.

A simple example would be as follows:

> Input: `3`, `(2, 4)`
>
> Output: `(3, 6)`

The output is `(3, 6)` because the second array value is twice as much as the first, so it deserves twice as much of the distribution (`2`) than the first array value does (`1`).

Another more complicated example:

> Input: `9`, `(4, 2, 5)`
>
> Output: `(7, 3, 10)`

In this example, the values do not distribute evenly. Instead, each array cell must be weighted to determine the percentage of the entire array. A sister array can be created when the values are converted to percentages:

> `(36.36%, 18.18%, 45.45%)`

Once the percentages are discovered, it can be determined that each percentage of the original number should be distributed as such. The problem is that only integral portions can be distributed, so instead of `3.24` being added to the first array value, only `3` can be added, and so on. The reason the third array value gets the lion's share of the value (`5` instead of `4`, rounding *up* from `45.45%` of `9`, `4.05`) is because it has the highest percentage of the sum of array values.

My question is this: What function returns such a transformed array of integers when given an array of integers and another integer value to distribute as evenly as possible into them?

**NOTE**: If my answers is off on the second example, providing proof of why in addition to a function that provides a different output is enough for a sufficient answer.